# Не добавляются данные при использовании атрибута disabled элемента submit

Tags: angular, angular4, angular5

Есть форма с кнопкой типа submit, при клике
на которой должны вставляться данные на сервере, считанные
из input. При использовании атрибута
disabled="carForm.invalid" вставка не происходит, если
убираю - все нормально вставляется.

```js
<form action="" [formGroup]="carForm" (ngSubmit)="addCar()">
    <input class="form-control" name="Name" placeholder="" formControlName="carName" />
        <div class="alert alert-danger"
            *ngIf='carForm.controls["carName"].invalid && carForm.controls["carName"].touched'>
                Не указано имя
        </div>    
        <input type="submit" id="btn_send" value="Add Car" [disabled]="carForm.invalid">    
</form>
```

```
В методе компонента всё нормально работает, если убираю 
[disabled]="carForm.invalid"
```